# Anki: Displayed size does not match specified size

Tags: scaling, anki

In Anki, the sizes I specify in LaTeX encoding do not match those that are displayed.

MWE: Leaving the header and footer at the Anki default of

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\special{papersize=3in,5in}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}
\begin{document}
```

and

```
\end{document}
```

respectively, typing `[latex]\rule{1cm}{1cm}[/latex]` (and adjusting the note's CSS so that the produced image is not resized with `img{max-height:none; max-width:none;}`) will display an approximately 1.75cm by 1.75cm square, as opposed to the expected 1cm by 1cm square.

**How can I adjust this so that the size I specify in LaTeX is accurately displayed?**

The obvious solution would be some way to scale an entire LaTeX document, but my searches for such have been unfruitful.

I would prefer not to resort to re-scaling the actual images produced by Anki (hence the CSS), as this renders them blurry.

What I have tried:

- Adjusting the font size will not fix the MWE above, as LaTeX still
  thinks that 1cm is ~1.75cm.
- Adjusting the paper size does not seem to do anything.

What others have suggested, and I have tried:

- `\scalebox` and `\resizebox` (after putting `\usepackage{graphicx}`/`\usepackage{graphics}` in header) do not resize anything visually, but can cause other LaTeX objects to register them as smaller.  For example, with the modified header and default footer,

  `[latex]\scalebox{0.5}{\rule{1cm}{1cm}}foo bar[/latex]`

  will produce a >1cm box blocking the word `foo`, followed by the word `bar`.
  (Suggested by @John Kormylo)

Edit: Info on anki LaTeX compile process.  Removed, see my answer if you really want to know.

Edit: Semi-failed attempt, Removed, see my answer if you really want to know.

Comment: I would say this is a Anki problem rather than a LaTeX problem.  For example \sbox0{\rule{1cm}{1cm}}\the\ht0\par\the\wd0 should return 28.45274pt (1cm).

Comment: You could use \scalebox to compensate, though.

Comment: I learned that dvipng [does not honor the \special{papersize=width,height} command](https://www.mail-archive.com/dvipng@nongnu.org/msg00130.html).

Answer (score 1):

The previous solution I found ([previous solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/320139/how-to-get-anki-working-with-tikz-based-packages/320140)) uses the `standalone` class, and does not handle the `graphicx` package well, nor images, which are extremely useful in anki.  To fix this, I have instead figured out the following.

In Anki, putting the following as the LaTeX header:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{environ}
\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}
\NewEnviron{ankicard}{\fontsize{16}{19}\selectfont\scalebox{0.6}{\BODY}}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{ankicard}
```

and the following as the footer:

```
\end{ankicard}\end{document}
```

and, in the `Edit LaTeX build process` addon to anki, putting the following:

```
#original setting
#newLaTeX = \
#[
#    ["latex", "-interaction=nonstopmode", "tmp.tex"],
#    ["dvipng", "-D", "200", "-T", "tight", "tmp.dvi", "-o", "tmp.png"]
#]

# ======

#Setting for pdflatex compilation
newLaTeX = \
[
  ["pdflatex", "-interaction=nonstopmode", "tmp.tex"],
  ["pdfcrop", "tmp.pdf"],
  ["pdftoppm", "-png", "-r", "200", "tmp-crop.pdf", "tmp"],
  ["ankirename.bat"]
]

# make the changes
import anki.latex
anki.latex.latexCmds = newLaTeX
```

(only the second list is new, rest comes w/ addon), and putting `ankirename.bat` somewhere in your path, with the contents

```
rename tmp-1.png tmp.png
```

Should scale all (newly generated) LaTeX in anki to the appropriate size.  If it does not, you can fiddle with the `0.6` parameter in `scalebox` in the `ankicard` environment of the LaTeX header.  This should also allow placing and scaling graphics in anki, and should allow LaTeX to automatically wrap any text that you type that is too long without the `varwidth` package that the `standalone` class requires to do so, which seems to conflict with `graphicx`.

The explanation:

As [the previous solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/320139/how-to-get-anki-working-with-tikz-based-packages/320140) has said, some packages require the `pdflatex` compiler, which does not always output all of the necessary data in any produced `.dvi` files, so not only will anki's default use of `latex ...` not work, the second command of `dvipng ...` won't work either, so we have to change both of these.

Switching to `pdflatex ...` compilation is straightforward, ripped right from the linked answer.  This will produce a file called `tmp.pdf`

However, if we want to use the `article` document type (as anki uses by default) to allow inserting and scaling images and such, we can't use the `standalone` class like the other answer mentions, so not only do we not get the automatic compilation to `.png` that `standalone` provides, we don't get its automatic cropping either.  Fortunately, these are both easy to fix, with `pdfcrop`, which produces a file `tmp-crop.pdf`, and `pdftoppm`, which produces a file called `tmp-1.png`.  (Note: if `pdfcrop --debug` is saying that it both can and can't find ghostscript, double check that `C:\Windows\System32` is in your path.)

Lastly, anki does not actually use a shell to execute these commands, it simply runs the executables. But because `rename` and `mv` are not (as I infer from the fact that they produce errors here) actual programs, but rather functions in a shell, we cannot put `rename tmp-1.png tmp.png` directly into the LaTeX build process file.  Instead, we just add a layer of indirection and have it call a `.bat` file that does that for us.