# \defcitealias not recognized (natbib)

Tags: natbib

Anyone know why I am getting an undefined control sequence error when trying to use \defcitealias in natbib, even though natbib otherwise seems to be working?

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{natbib}

\defcitealias{foo}{bar}

\begin{document}

\citetalias{foo}
\citet{handk}

\bibliographystyle{chicago}
\bibliography{all.bib}

\end{document}


This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015) (preloaded 
format=pdflatex)
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./Untitled-2.tex
LaTeX2e <2015/01/01>
Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/Users/firstnamelastname/Library/texmf/tex/latex/natbib.sty)
./Untitled-2.tex:4: Undefined control sequence.
l.4 \defcitealias
                 {foo}{bar}
?
```

[image: foobar]

Comment: What about this fix https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/319983/undefined-control-sequence-pgfsyspdfmark-converting-standalone-tikz-with-pdflat?

Comment: Aside: It should be `\bibliography{all}`, not `\bibliography{all.bib}`.

Comment: Another aside: How old is the `natbib.sty` file? Any chance you could update your TeX distribution from TeXLive2015 to TeXLive2017?

Comment: You have a local natbib.sty in `/Users/firstnamelastname/Library/texmf/tex/latex/natbib.sty` rename it to something else and try again.

Comment: Thanks, reloading natbib and then using kolygr's answer did the trick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the solution of my comment and didn't work but gave me an error about unknown option  `english` in `babel`... I fixed it adding these lines before calling `\defcitealias`:

```
\providecommand{\pgfsyspdfmark}[3]{}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
```

Full MWE:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{natbib}
\providecommand{\pgfsyspdfmark}[3]{}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\defcitealias{foo}{bar}

\begin{document}

\citetalias{foo}
\citet{handk}

\bibliographystyle{chicago}
\bibliography{all.bib}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Doesn't work for me, either with or without babel. So the idea is that the problem has to do with pdflatex?

Comment: Just out of idle curiosity: where does `\pgfsyspdfmark` come from, and how does it fit in?

Comment: @Mico see the first comment of the question... I have no idea and will not search now... May be some other time but this fix is described there